# How to change case from upper to lower of a words 1st letter if the same word occures at least one time in lower case using regex only

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I've created the following RegEx in Python 3 to find all lower case words in a text and back reference the first letter and the tail of that word. Example:

```
w          ord
^          ^^^
|          |
1st letter tail
```

Afterwards I use a for loop to replace all occurrences of matches with the first group converted to uppercase and the unaltered tail with the lowercase first letter followed by the unaltered tail.

```
str = "Some text here and some more after that. Something that should remain untouched."
for match in re.finditer(r"\b([a-z])([a-z]+)\b", str):
    # print(match.group(1).upper() + match.group(2)) # just for debugging
    str = re.sub(r"\b" + match.group(1).upper() + match.group(2) + r"\b", match.group(1) + match.group(2), str)

print(str) #print the desired result
```

Is there a way to do this in Python 3 with a single regular expression and no additional procedural code? It feels like there should be a more elegant way but I don't see it (yet).

For completeness: If the code is applied to the string stored in str this is the result:
some text here and some more after that. Something that should remain untouched.

Please note that the RegEx-Replace may only match whole words but not partial words. The 5th word in my text is "some" this causes the 1st word's ("Some") 1st letter to to be converted to lower case but leaves the word "Something", the 2nd sentence starts with, untouched.

Comment: Can you just describe *what* you're trying to get instead of *how* you're trying to do it? A simple before and after should suffice.

Comment: Well I want to convert all words starting with an upper case letter to the same word in lower case IF the word occurrs at least one time in lower case in the text. The code I posted does that properly but I'm tring to get rid of the for and just perform the task with a RegEx only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with the `re module` since it doesn't support variable length lookbehind and since when you use an inline modifier like `(?i)`, it is set for all the pattern and you can't turn it off. It is possible to do it with the new [`regex module`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) with this pattern:

```
\b([A-Z][a-z]*)\b(?:(?=.*\b(?=[a-z]+\b)(?i)\1\b)|(?<=\b(?=[a-z]+\b)(?i)\1\b.+))
```

However, I'm not sure this is a more "elegant" way.

It is possible to test the pattern with [regexstorm.net/tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%28%5BA-Z%5D%5Ba-z%5D%2a%29%5Cb%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3D.%2a%5Cb%28%3F%3D%5Ba-z%5D%2B%5Cb%29%28%3Fi%29%5C1%5Cb%29%7C%28%3F%3C%3D%5Cb%28%3F%3D%5Ba-z%5D%2B%5Cb%29%28%3Fi%29%5C1%5Cb.%2B%29%29&i=Some%20text%20here%20and%20some%20more%20after%20that.%20Something%20that%20should%20remain%20untouched.%20That) *(since .net regex engine allows variable length lookbehinds too.)*

Note that the scope of the inline modifier is limited to the subpattern after it and ends at the first closing parenthesis.

Comment: Awesome that's exactly what I've been looking for. It became a bit larger than I expected, after taking my time going through it I think its pretty straight forward. Also BIG thanks for the regexstorm link. I didn't know that page before, it is awesome to do some quick tests on regexps and getting some visual feedback quickly.